# Azure Blob user actions logging

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I've been going through Azure blob documentation and [Storage Analytics Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging) but I don't see how to enable logging on user level. So, there is company Azure plan, each employee logs in with own credentials, but when we use Azure Storage Explorer (desktop version) I don't see anywhere logged in which user uploaded, deleted... which files/folders to the blob. What did we miss to do here?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format#log-entry-format-20

In blob log format version 2.0 only, we have UserPricipalName.
I did tried, While the field is a uuid. Which is not user friendly.
Just for your reference.